# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.00'

Tags: python, int, type-conversion

I have a string in Python like that:

```
l = "0.00 0.00"
```

And I want to convert it in a list of two numbers.

The following instruction does not work:

```
int(l.strip(" \n").split(" ")[0])
```

Apparently the function `int()` can convert  string like `0` or `00` to an int, but it does not work with `0.0`.

Is there a way to convert `0.0`?

A.

Comment: **Integers** cannot have decimal points.

Comment: In fact `>>> int(0.0)` is `0` !

Comment: That code converts an existing double to an integer.

Comment: What would you expect `0.9` to be? What about `9.9`? Truncate `[0, 9]` or round `[1, 10]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to first convert to `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
int(Decimal('0.00'))
```

if you are sure that fractional part is always zero then faster would be to use float

```
int(float('0.00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For floating point conversion from a string you can use following, here assumption is that you need `int` for integral values in string

```
 def conv(st):
    try:
        return int(st)
    except ValueError: #If you get a ValueError
        return float(st)

 conv(l.strip(" \n").split(" ")[0])
```